# Excel pivot table: how to get grand average when counting text fields

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

My boss wants to have the average registrations for each countries for our courses.
I have four fields in my table : *"Course"*, *"registration-ID"*, *"Country"*, *"year"*.
In the pivot I created, I added *"country"* to rows, *"year"* to column and *"Registration-ID"* to values.

Here is an subset of the data, and a pivot table I created based on this subset: 
[Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sZWXn.png)
[Pivot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IWI9O.png)

I added my grand average column to the end. As we only have two years in this data subset, calculating the average is trivial, I only have to divide by two.

But as I want to create charts based on this, it would be much better if I could have that result directly in my pivot table. This way I can update the data and have my new results right away without any manual input.

If I right click on the pivot table and click on "Summarize value by>" then on "average", I get "#DIV/0!" errors everywhere on my pivot table. I guess it is linked to the fact that registration-ID is a text field.

Comment: Because you're average text value. I suggest you add auxiliary column in data source about Count.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Lee. I am not sure how to add a count to my dataset, and how it would help me? Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Hey again Lee. I just saw this again, and now I understand completely what you meant. By adding a count in my dataset linked to each course, I can then do an average on the count, as this is a number. Thanks for your answer. I am not sure how I can accept your answer as we are several months after the fact. If a mod sees this, maybe thy can mark your answer as accepted?